# What is the correct implementation of a callback function?

Tags: callback, higher-order-functions

See two functions below. They lead to the same output [4,6], but are different in set up. Is it correct that only the first function makes use of a callback function? Is the first function preferred(more elegant?) over the other one? And is it correct that 'map' is the higher-order function in the second example as it makes use of the callback function that is within its brackets?
Thanks!

```
function processArray(arr,callback){
return arr.map(callback)
}

processArray([2,3], function(number){return number*2})
```

AND

```
function processArray(arr){
return arr.map(function(element){
return otherFunction(element)})
}

function otherFunction(number){
return number*2}

processArray([2,3])
```

Comment: If *calling* a function from a function would count as higher order function, pretty much all functions are higher order, since you're typically making calls to *some* function all the time.

Comment: The point of a named function is encapsulation and code re-usability. If you do not intend to re-use the callback, and the language you are using has no performance drawbacks, the first example is both more readable and more re-usable.

Comment: Got it, thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it correct that only the first function makes use of a callback function?

No. `arr.map` takes a callback. You just don't see its definition here.

> Is the first function preferred(more elegant?) over the other one?

Yes, but (probably) not for the reason you think. The anonymous function wrapping `otherFunction` is pointless. You can also write

```
function processArray(arr){
  return arr.map(otherFunction)
}

function otherFunction(number){
  return number*2
}

processArray([2,3])
```

> And is it correct that 'map' is the higher-order function in the second example as it makes use of the callback function that is within its brackets?

In the first example, both `processArray` and `map` are higher-order functions. In the second, yes, only `map` is higher-order.

It's easy to inspect a function to see if it is a higher-order function: is one (or more) of its parameters invoked?